# Can't connect laravel application to distant database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database

This is my first project on Laravel.

I've been given a distant database to which I try to connect but I can't.

I inserted a test table in phpMyAdmin and I tried to get the data.

I modified  the .env file to fill with the database informations.

I created a TestController :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class Test extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(): string
    {
        $tests = DB::table('test')->get();
        return view('test', ['tests'=>$tests]);
    }
}
```

then I loop on $tests and I try to display the data but I have no result and I get this error :

[image]

.env :

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:nAA971RXUyJuOcG2GzTBxKMhqfdNs7j1lGqszq9m+CI=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=https://***/
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=***
DB_USERNAME=***
DB_PASSWORD=***
```

database.php :

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is that the whole error message?

Comment: @geertjanknapen yes

Comment: Are you running the application by `php artisan serve`? If so, did you restart when you changed the .env file.
Did you try `php artisan config:clear`?

Comment: @ruben you dont need to write HTTPS:// in the DB_HOST just the domain or the IP

Comment: Are you running your app in docker-compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to write HTTPS:// in the DB_HOST just the domain or the IP